# Graphing piecewise function

Tags: function, matlab, graph, differential-equations, piecewise

I've got the following function F(phi):
[image: F] in MATLAB:

```
function out = F(p, a, b)
phi = mod(p,2*pi);
out = (0      <= phi & phi < a     ).*(phi/a) ...
    + (a      <= phi & phi < pi/2  ).*((phi*(b-1)/((pi/2)-a))-(a*(b-1))/((pi/2)-a)+1)...
    + (pi/2   <= phi & phi < pi-a  ).*((phi*(1-b)/((pi/2)-a))-((pi-a)*(1-b))/((pi/2)-a)+1)...
    + (pi-a   <= phi & phi < pi+a  ).*(-phi/a + pi/a)...
    + (pi+a   <= phi & phi < 3*(pi/2)).*((phi*(1-b)/((pi/2)-a))-(((pi+a)*(1-b))/((pi/2)-a))-1)...
    + (3*pi/2 <= phi & phi < 2*pi-a).*((phi*(b-1)/((pi/2)-a))-(((2*pi-a)*(b-1))/((pi/2)-a))-1)...
    + (2*pi-a <= phi & phi < 2*pi  ).*(phi/a-2*pi/a);
end
```

```
gamma = 1.01;
[t,phi] = ode45(@(t,x)gamma-F(x,pi/6, 0.5), [0,100], -pi);
figure();  plot(t,phi);
ylim([-pi, pi]);
yticks(-pi:pi:pi);
yticklabels((-1:1)+ "\pi");
grid on; grid minor
```

I've only got something like this:

[image: plot].

I don't know how to make a graph of piecewise function  phi(t) from it.
Could you please tell me how to do this graph to be in the form of a piecewise function like this?

[image: form]

- it starts with `-π` (on Y axes)
- then it continues till it reaches value = `π` (on Y axes)
- then it again switches to the initial value (`-π`)

Comment: It would have been nice if you edited the old question, rather than delete it and posting a new one, just to preserve comments and history. Anyway, `F` is a piecewise function, because it has a different expression for different intervals. It is also a periodic function, because of the `mod` call at the start. You then compute `phi` from 0 to 100. But note that you are plotting the integral of your function, not the function itself, and the integral will not have discontinuities like you show in your desired output. The integral is increasing because your function is always non-negative.

Comment: @CrisLuengo that's true. but there's no way to split `phi` into several pieces (not from 0 to 100 but from 0 to some x1, x1 to x2,..., xk to 100)?

Comment: You can compute those pieces separately, and concatenate them, or just plot them separately to the same axes. You need `hold on` to plot multiple times to the same axes.